# Android won't boot after accidentally uninstalling a system app

Tags: boot

My android version is 4.2.2 so while I was installing an app on the system using Moborobo I think I might have accidentally removed a system app.
I have checked all over the internet and I am pretty sure I don't have access to my original ROM that comes with the device. Even Clockworkmod for my device isn't available so I hadn't made any backup.
I have tried to factory reset using the recovery option that came with the phone and it boots fine. When I power it off or reboot it won't start until I do another factory reset. Where do I start to fix this? I have connected the phone to ADT but I can't get the logcat to pause so that I can post the output here. Meanwhile if there is anything I can do let me know as I try to get the logcat output

Comment: You need to find and reinstall the stock ROM. I think that's your only option.

Comment: Well, is it possible for you to share your device information like model number, manufacturer etc. We couldn't help you out with the flashing process until or unless you don't mention the ... !

Comment: @Peter Carlos 
Model number Bird Leader
Brand Bird
Android Version 4.2.2
Build number MP.V1.2
Custom build version MX1029W_BIRD_LEADER_K-V1.03.20140324-QHD

Comment: @qualebs "I can't get the logcat to pause"? `adb logcat -f <file_name>` saves the output into a file, which you then can edit with your favorite text-editor to cut'n'paste the relevant parts.